# Partition swapping in Hive

Tags: hive

What is the impact on running queries in Hive if i swap the partition using

```
ALTER TABLE user_data
    PARTITION (name = 'ABC')
    SET LOCATION = 'db/partitions/new';
```

Does this command wait until queries finished executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive translate your query into temporary Map/Reduce job and that job executed on behalf of your hive query.When you submit hive query it creates a Map/Reduce job based on your query and that job gets executed and you get a result from that job. But if you `ALTER` your hive query and change partition or anything during the execution of query, command will not wait to finish your running job, it will alter your table and you will get result from your previous query unless or until you kill your previous job.

Best way to understand this is **try and run**. Just submit your hive query and redirect it to store the result into file and then change the partition and again submit the query and redirect it to store the result into file. Verify the both output.